# What is the best way to turn a HTML start and end tag into a function?

Tags: php, html

I have a complex HTML tag, with many attributes and it appears in very different parts of the code.

Example:

```
<div class="blabla" data-test="blablabla" ... data-another-attribute="blabla" >
    <some complex html code ... >
</div>
```

And I do not want to repeat this `<div></div>` with all its attributes in different parts of the code as it changes quite often during development.

If I create a function like this (example in PHP):

```
function myDivStart() { ?>
    <div class="blabla" data-attribute="blablabla" data-another-attribute="blabla">
<?php }
```

then my resulting code would look like

```
<?php myDivStart(); ?>
    <some html code ... >
</div>
```

and the finishing `</div>` would look kind of out-of-place, since there is no visual starting `<div>`. My text editor would also not parse this correctly and syntax highlighting is messed up.

Then, if I create another function for the closing `</div>`, it would be a very silly function indeed:

```
function myDivEnd() { ?>
    </div>
<?php }
```

and turn the original code into

```
<?php myDivStart(); ?>
    <some html code ... >
<?php myDivEnd(); ?>
```

This would solve the syntax highlighting problem, but it still feels very unclean to have such a silly function to close.

**UPDATE:** Storing the HTML code in a variable and passing that to a function would not really solve the problem neither, as the HTML inside a variable would not be parsed correctly with syntax highlighting.

```
$myHTML = '<a href="...">A very long and complex piece of html</a>';
<?php myDiv($myHTML); ?>
```

My text editor would not have syntax highlighting there.
And doing the following would also make the code disorderly, as the $myHTML code comes before the `<div>` and actually, logically belongs after it.

```
$myHTML = ?>
    <a href="...">A very long and complex piece of html</a>
<?php ;
myDiv($myHTML);
```

Is there any pattern that would solve for this?

Comment: you are not returning html there. Return php string in function and echo the string which will be html

Comment: `<div  <?= myDivAttributes() ?>> // complex HTML... </div>` ? i.e. only have the attributes in the function not the `div` tag.

Comment: @RyanVincent That actually makes the most sense. So simple I didn't think about it. I would accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it's always the same tag you can use a variable or a constant instead of a function.

E.g.

```
$openTag = "<div class=\"blabla\" data-test=\"blablabla\" ... data-another-attribute=\"blabla\" >";
$closeTag = "</div>";
```

If you have varying parts of that tag then you can instead indeed make a function, e.g.:

```
function openingDiv($class) {
     return "<div class=\"$class\" data-test=\"blablabla\" ... data-another-attribute=\"blabla\" >"
}

function closingDiv() {
      return "</div>";
}
```

You can also make it a bit more sophisticated:

```
function wrapContentInDiv($content) {
     return "<div class=\"$class\" data-test=\"blablabla\" ... data-another-attribute=\"blabla\" >$content</div>";
}
```

Example uses:

```
<?php 
$openTag = "<div class=\"blabla\" data-test=\"blablabla\" ... data-another-attribute=\"blabla\" >";
$closeTag = "</div>";
 ?>
 <leading html>
  ....

  <?php echo $openTag ?>
  <some html here> 
  <?php echo $closeTag ?>
  ...
  <?php echo $openTag ?>
  <some other html here> 
  <?php echo $closeTag ?>
  <trailing html>
```

You can take this one step further and define your code in a separate php file:

e.g. **config.php**

Then you can:

```
  <?php 
  require_once("config.php") 
  ?>
  ...
```

Update:

You could also use a template e.g. file **complexDiv.php**

```
<div class="blabla" data-test="blablabla" ... data-another-attribute="blabla" >
```

Use this as below:

```
 <leading html>
  ....

  <?php //Set any parameters that complexDiv.php needs here
  include 'complexDiv.php' 
   ?>
  <some html here> 
  </div>
  ...
  <?php include 'complexDiv.php' ?>
  <some other html here> 
  </div>
  <trailing html>
```

I suspect that before long you'll realise that its worth switching to a template engine like smarty of blade.

Comment: The <div> tag has several parameters, and thus a constant would not be appropriate in my case. The content also is a very large and complex piece of code that I don't want to put in a variable.

Comment: @RoelVermeulen Added one more option. Also what you describe is the problem that templating engines were built to solve.

Comment: I don't think this problem would be solved with a template engine. The <div> with its attributes would still need to be repeated in the different places, albeit with {variables} instead of <?php code ?>. And I do not want to repeat the code because I change the number of attributes and their names from time to time. And now I have to change them in many places. With a template engine, I would still have to change those attributes in every occurrence.

Comment: @RoelVermeulen You can have a composite view comprised of many partial views. One of those parts can be your div. Laravel has a good engine you can check out (blade).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the `some HTML code` is but you could do something like this pseudocode

```
$some_html=''; //your html code goes here as a string

myDiv($some_html);

function myDiv( $arg ){
 echo <div class="blabla" data-attribute="blablabla" data-another-attribute="blabla">
  echo $arg;
 echo </div>
}
```

Comment: I understand, but if the $some_html is a very large and complex piece of code that I would need to store in a variable first, it would not make for pretty code neither. My syntax highlighter would not recognize the HTML tags inside a variable.

Comment: There is no other way. I guess you are stuck with your start() and end() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can first prepare the HTML on a different file and include that file on the function where the div tags are waiting for them to wrap that content of yours. Hope it helps.

```
function wrapperDiv() {
     $html = '';
     $html .= '<div class="blabla" data-test="blablabla" ... data-another-attribute="blabla" >';
     $html .= include_once 'body.php';
     $html .= '</div>';
     return $html;
}

wrapperDiv();
```

Comment: That would not help with the syntax highlighting as the <div> in your example is in a string. Also, the include_once (the complex HTML code I speak about) is different in the different parts of the code, and I cannot save it in a constant 'body.php' file as you suggest.